# Eclipse error message while trying to open and RSE project

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which messed up my existing Eclipse setup. I tried to first re-instal my Yiiclipse and RSE plugins but I kept getting error messages, so I decided to re-install Eclipse. I used version 3.8 which I installed from Ubuntu's Software Center, thus I removed it, deleted my workspace and .eclipse folders and re-installed but it still doesn't work.

When I add a new Yiiclipse project to Eclipse through RSE it takes almost 10 minutes for Eclipse to import the project then it hangs. After I restart and try to open a PHP file from the project it gives the following error message:

> Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)...

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Try to open the Error log view and look for recent entries. There should be a full exception trace - without that is is virtually impossible to tell what may have gone wrong.

Comment: This is what I have found in the log file prior to the other message that I pasted above: `!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-03-28 23:01:55.464
!MESSAGE Unable to create editor ID org.eclipse.php.editor: Editor could not be initialized.
!STACK 0`

Comment: And one more thing : `An internal error occurred during: "Initializing PHP Tooling".`

Comment: Hmm, strange. There is usually a more detailed exception trace. Sorry, I am no help this way.

Comment: Maybe you could try and connect the PHP Tooling Developers. I could only find their development mailing list on the project page, see https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt/contact

Comment: Thanks Zoli, but as it turned out after hours of investigation the problem was that the Dynamic Language Toolkit plugin was missing and that caused the issue. Thank you one more time for taking the time and try to help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was that after I re-installed Eclipse I had to install DLTK plugin, which solved my problem.

Reinstallation of Eclipse was not a cake-walk, thus I created a [blog post](http://redevtion.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-re-install-eclipse-38-ide-with.html#sbs) how I achieved to put together a working Eclipse 3.8 environment with Yii and RSE support on Ubunto 14.04 LTS staring from scratch.